# getting pypar2 while executing .sh file in Ubuntu

Tags: sh, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to execute .sh file in ubuntu. I can execute the same from terminal.
But while executing from gui I do not get the option like Run with terminal and instaed Pypar2 pops up.how can i remove default program for sh files?\

and how can I get options when I double click on .sh file?

Comment: same problem here...

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.
Open Files application. Then Edit->Preferences->Behavior Tab. Here you have a section "Executable Text Files". Check "Ask each time".